# C# Loop through XML Parent Element with XmlTextReader

Tags: c#, xml, loops

I have XML file like this

```
<Alarms>
    <Alarm>
        <Date>2013-10-05</Date>
        <Time>11:50</Time>
    </Alarm>
    <Alarm>
        <Date>2013-10-05</Date>
        <Time>11:55</Time>
    </Alarm>
    <Alarm>
        <Date>2013-10-05</Date>
        <Time>12:05</Time>
    </Alarm>
    <Alarm/>
</Alarms>
```

And I'm tring to read it using following codes

```
XmlTextReader objXmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader("Alarms.xml");
while (objXmlTextReader.Read())
{
    objXmlTextReader.ReadToFollowing("Date");
    MessageBox.Show(objXmlTextReader.ReadElementContentAsString());

    objXmlTextReader.ReadToFollowing("Time");
    MessageBox.Show(objXmlTextReader.ReadElementContentAsString());
}
objXmlTextReader.Close();
```

But it doesn't loop each 'Alarm' parent element. Only shows 2013-10-05 and 11:55 in message box. Can't figure out what's wrong here? Please help. I need to loop through all date and time elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using Linq and System.Xml.Linq?

The code for that looks like this:

```
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load("Alarms.xml");
        foreach (var x in xdoc.Root.Elements("Alarm")) {
            Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
            var date = x.Element("Date");
            var time = x.Element("Time");
            Console.WriteLine("Date = {0}", date == null ? "<empty>": date.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Time = {0}", time == null ? "<empty>": time.Value);
            }
```